# Converting for-loop into List

Tags: python, list, for-loop

i was working on this program:

```
  for n in range (0,31):
      if n%2 is 0:
          if (n%2)is 0 and (n%5)is 0:
              print(n)
```

i want the output to be like this, in list.

```
[0,10,20,30]
```

i tried to add list.append,

```
hehe = []

    for n in range (0,31):
        if n%2 is 0:
            if (n%2)is 0 and (n%5)is 0:
                hehe.append(n)
                print(hehe)
```

but the result is like this.

```
[0]
[0, 10]
[0, 10, 20]
[0, 10, 20, 30]
```

how do i make it into [0,10,20,30] only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the print outside the forloop.

Comment: "i was working on this code" this code... meaning it isn't your code, right? A for loop is a programming construct, a list is a data structure. You do not "convert a for loop to a list".

Comment: thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: vote to close as typo

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `print(hehe)` is inside the for loop, it is printed every time the loop is called.

Simply call it outside the loop to print it only after `hehe` is finished being formed.

Note that

```
[x for x in range(31) if not i % 10]  # anything divisible by 2 and 5 is also divisible by 10
```

is much cleaner and produces the same result as your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `print` is inside the loop, it's printing it out every iteration. You want to move the print statement to the end. Also, your first `if` statement is redundant since you're doing the same check again in the second one, so you can remove it:

```
hehe = []
for n in range(0,31):
    if (n%2)==0 and (n%5)==0:
        hehe.append(n)
print(hehe)
```

Finally, this kind of loop is an ideal candidate for a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
hehe = [n for n in range(0, 31) if (n%2)==0 and (n%5)==0]
print(hehe)
```

Also note that you should check values against `0` using `==` instead of `is`, since it's a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It's a formatting issue. It should be like this:

```
hehe = []

for n in range (0,31):
    if n%2 is 0:
        if (n%2)is 0 and (n%5)is 0:
            hehe.append(n)
print(hehe)
```

You need to put the print statement outside the for-loop, so it doesn't get called every time you add data to `hehe`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hehe = [i for i in range(31) if i%2 == 0 and i%5 == 0]
```

or

```
hehe = [i for i in range(31) if i % 10 == 0]
```